# Is it grammatical and idiomatic to use 2 successive verb followed by one objective?

Tags: grammar

I said "I've accepted and upvoted it" just now, then I realized this kind of expression may be not grammatical.

For example, `grab and eat an apple`, is this grammatical?

Which piece of gramma this of expression follows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly. There is nothing wrong with doing this. I think there is a Geek-derived name for this usage, but I can't recall it. You could think of it as a special species of elision. I myself am particularly fond of the similar form in which a repeated **verb** is elided, such as the famous examples from [Flanders and Swann's "Have some Madeira"](https://genius.com/Flanders-and-swann-madeira-mdear-lyrics):

> - He hastened to put out the cat, the wine, his cigar, and the lamps .
> - She lowered her standards by raising her glass, her courage, her eyes, and his hopes.